# Theorems on base for a topology

Tags: general-topology

There are two theorems on base for a topology which I cannot distinguish between.
I cannot see the difference between the two theorems. They are the following.
They are theorems from the book: Introduction to topology by Gameline and Greene.

Thm 4.1: A family $\mathscr B$ of open subsets of a topological space $X$ is a base for the topology of $X$ if and only if for each $x \in X$ and each nbhd $U$ of $x$ there exists $V \in \mathscr B$ such that $x \in V$ and $V \subset U$.

Thm 4.2: A family $\mathscr B$ of subsets of a set $X$ is a base for a topology of $X$ if and only if $\mathscr B$ has the following two properties:

1) Each $x \in X$ lies in at least one set in $\mathscr B$

2) If $U,V \in \mathscr B$ and $x \in U \cap V$, then there exists $W \in \mathscr B$ such that $x \in W$ and $W \subset U \cap V$.

Isn't property 1) of Thm 4.2 exactly the same as Thm 4.1? But why is the reason for making Thm 4.2 and adding property 2? What is the difference between the two theorems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Theorem 4.1, $X$ is already a topological space and we are determining if a family $\mathscr{B}$ of *open subsets* is a base for this topology of $X$ whereas in Theorem 4.2, $X$ is just a set without any topology defined on it and we are checking whether we can use the family $\mathscr{B}$ of subsets of $X$ to define a topology on $X$.